Is there a maximum possible value for the coefficient of variation?
For a sample of size n of only positive values, what is the largest possible value of the coefficient of variation (CV, defined as SD/Mean)?

Theres no proof there but the bound is here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/633518/805 . Nick Cox gives a useful/relevant link as a comment as well

Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18621/maximum-value-of-coefficient-of-variation-for-bounded-data-set

Using arguments similar to those presented elsewhere here on CV for bounding the variance, we find that the CV is maximized by a dataset of $n-1$ zeros and a single positive value.  Since the CV is scale-invariant, we might as well assume $x$ has a "nice" value: I choose $x=n.$  (The possibility $x=0$ needn't be considered, for then the CV is undefined.)
The first two non-central moments therefore are (by their very definitions) equal to
$$m_1 = \frac{n-1}{n}(0) + \frac{1}{n}(n) = 1$$
and
$$m_2 = \frac{n-1}{n}(0)^2 + \frac{1}{n}(n)^2 = n,$$
whence the upper limit on the CV is
$$CV = \frac{\sqrt{m_2 - m_1^2}}{m_1} = \frac{\sqrt{n-1}}{1} = \sqrt{n-1}.$$

Thanks for the instant answer!

Your first sentence has an unfortunate collision of two meanings of CV. Better to link specifically to what you mean by "elsewhere here on CV".

I suspect that was a deliberate humorous choice

@whuber. Why  the "-1*m1^2" term? seems to me that is wrong and the answer is sqrt(n)...

It depends on whether you are using an estimate of the variance in the calculation of the CV or the variance itself.  Here, I use the variance.  As you note, if you are interested in bounding this particular CV estimate, then you must multiply it by $\sqrt{n/(n-1)},$ giving $\sqrt{n}$ as the upper bound.  The "$-m_1^2$" term comes from a standard formula for the variance, btw--it cannot be omitted.

Also known as sample vs population variance.
